# Should the first h in Nehemiah be silent? If so, why?

Tags: pronunciation, silent-letters, transliteration

I hear many native speakers do not pronounce the first h in Nehemiah. However, I also found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUOCe4vwI9U) pronouncing this h. I am wondering about the correct pronunciation of Nehemiah in English.

1. This word is transliterated from the Hebrew word נְחֶמְיָה‎. If we try to pronounce it in the Hebrew way, the first h should not be silent.
2. I am not sure if there is a [phonic rule regarding silent h's](https://www.really-learn-english.com/english-spelling-rules-silent-h.html) in English which is applicable here.

So, my question is: should the first h in Nehemiah be silent? If so, why?

Comment: One might ask equally about why the I in _Nehemiah_ isn't pronounced like EE, as it is in Hebrew.

Comment: @JohnLawler, exactly. Do you have an answer to your own question?

Comment: The person speaking in the youtube video is not a native English speaker, and his pronunciation should be taken with a grain of salt. As a native speaker of American English, I have rarely if ever heard the first 'h' pronounced.

Comment: @Zuriel The answer to both questions is that English spelling doesn't represent English pronunciation, so all letters are silent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In English, an "h" before an unaccented syllable in the middle of a word is often silent. This means that lots of English speakers are not going to pronounce the firat /h/ in Nehemiah (some will).

For example, *Lexico* dictionary says that it's pronounced in *[inhibit](https://www.lexico.com/definition/inhibit)* but that it can be silent in *[inhibition](https://www.lexico.com/definition/inhibition)*. This is because the stress shifts from the second syllable to the third one. Similarly, *Lexico* says it's silent in *[vehicle](https://www.lexico.com/definition/vehicle)*, but pronounced in *[vehicular](https://www.lexico.com/definition/vehicular)*, because the stress shifts from the first to the second syllable.

Comment: Same thing happens with *Rehoboam* in English. Many Biblical names from Hebrew containing *h* in transliteration are pronounced without /h/ in English due to the stress pattern.

Comment: I'm wondering if there are regional variations. I can't see any differences in dictionaries, but "vehicular" with an /h/ sounds more American than British. Maybe some people pronounce the /h/ more strongly.

Comment: And of course that's also the reason for _an historic occasion_ with the article _an_. The initial /h/ in _historical_ doesn't precede a stressed vowel, and so is often silent, leaving the word to start with a vowel that requires _an_.

Comment: And as @Yosef pointed out, the name has been Anglicized. More than that, it has come into (modern) English through centuries of usage in other languages, such as Latin.

Comment: @LarsH: I believe most biblical names were transliterated directly from the Hebrew, Aramaic, or Greek of the Old and New Testaments by the translators of the King James Bible. The more common names (like *John, Mary, Paul*) have indeed been anglicized through centuries of usage as actual names.

Comment: @Peter I stand corrected.